# Why Active admin not posting selected category associated with event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, categories

Just created an association with a model for category in activeadmin. The fields show up in the activeadmin area when adding an event and its aves the event but the category field has not been populated with the selected one and this is causing it to now not show on the frontend and give issues.

here is my setup

## category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    has_many :events
    has_many :profiles

end
```

## admin/category.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do

  controller do
     def permitted_params
        params.permit category: [:name, :slug]
     end
     def find_resource
      scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :name
      end
      f.actions
    end

end
```

## event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :event_image, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"

    validates_attachment_content_type :event_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    validates :title, :slug, :event_image, presence: true

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    belongs_to :category

end
```

## admin/event.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do

    controller do
       def permitted_params
          params.permit event: [:title, :slug, :event_image, :event_image_file_name, :eventdate, :description]
       end
       def find_resource
            scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
         end
    end

    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :title
      end
      f.inputs "Event Date" do
        f.input :eventdate, :date_select => true, :as => :date_picker, :use_month_names => true
      end
      f.inputs "Category" do
       f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Category.all
      end
      f.inputs "Biography" do
        f.input :description, :as => :ckeditor, :label => false, :input_html => {  :ckeditor => { :toolbar => 'Full', :height => 400 } }
      end
      f.inputs "Image" do
        f.file_field :event_image
      end
      f.actions
    end

end
```

## categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < InheritedResources::Base

    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end

    def show
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Then in my view I have got this:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
 <% for category in @categories %>
   <%= category.name %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously it cannot find it.

In my schema.rb I have this setup:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.date     "eventdate"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "event_image_file_name"
    t.string   "event_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "event_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "event_image_updated_at"
  end

add_index "events", ["category_id"], name: "index_events_on_category_id", unique: true
  add_index "events", ["slug"], name: "index_events_on_slug", unique: true
```

Can anyone figure out why it would not add it into the field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have defined the `@events` variable in the controller?

If you define an instance variable in the view, it has to be defined in the controller Action. Try `@events = Event.all` in your index action.

Comment: whats the name of your view? In your view your doing `@events.each...`, but @events is not defined in the controller action

Comment: The view is events/index the things is though when I save the category to the event in active admin I get this `Category Empty` next to the field when it shows what I have saved as a summary.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you define an instance variable in the view, it has to be defined in the controller Action. Try `@events = Event.all` in your index action.

Comment: is there a way of doing a statement like `if category == 'event-ended' do event.title`

Comment: You could do something like `if category.name == 'event_ended...'`, but I need more context. You could post a new question...

Comment: hang on it shows the category even if you have not selected it in the backend.